# python script to get external facing ips on my google cloud

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, python-requests

I have a bash script that print(to csv) me all the external ips that is in my gcp account(not just 1 project). But it takes few hours to complete. I want to get a python script to do that and I heard python is pretty quick.
Can you guys help? I am new to python world.

the command I am using in my script is below

```
   networkInterfaces[].accessConfigs[0].natIP.notnull().list():label=EXTERNAL_IP,
```

Comment: Of which external IP are you talking about? Your Compute Engine instance IP? Load balancer ips? Cloud Nat ips?

Comment: Compute instances public ips

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cloud Asset Inventory](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-resources) product that search for you all the assets in your project, folder and organization.

If you use the gcloud CLI, you can do that

```
gcloud asset search-all-resources \
  --scope=projects/<Number>\
  --asset-types=compute.googleapis.com/Instance --format=json | \
  jq -r ".[].additionalAttributes.networkInterfaces[].accessConfigs[].natIP"
```

Change the scope to search on folders or organisations.

---

Python isn't so fast (it's often the opposite when you have compute intensive app), but it's quick and convenient to write script in Python. If you can use the CLI, no advantage to use Python. You can also directly call the API through Python (or another language).

Let me know if this solution works for you, and if you need more, let me know your language.

Comment: console API is not active on our organization. How I can I get the required data without it?
And while I am here how do I get org number for my whole organization to see all the external ips associated? I have read access to view all the data.

Comment: guillaume blaquiere -I have been following you, you are the gcloud guru, is there a gcloud command apart from api to accomplish this?

Comment: If you want to read the data from several project, or even in your whole organization, you need to have access to the projects (or to the whole organization). So, you need at least compute viewer role at organization level (or in all project), and it's not really less than the  asset viewer role. In fact, you can achieve the same thing, by scanning each project, and each instances, and it will take more time. However, I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66856216/optimize-my-bash-script-with-gcloud-commands/66870173#66870173). If you know GO, it can help you.

Comment: Did the output change since March? I had to change your query to **jq -r ".[].additionalAttributes.externalIPs"**. For resources with no exernalIP null is printed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the external IP’s by following these steps:

1.Run the command in the console:

```
gcloud asset search-all-resources --scope=organizations/ORGANIZATION_NUMBER (projects/PROJECT_NUMBER) --asset-types=compute.googleapis.com/Instance > op.yaml
```

2.Install pyyaml using the command.

```
    pip install pyyaml
```

3.Open editor ,create new file:

```
filename.py
```

4.Run the following code in the file created:

```
import yaml
stream = open("op.yaml", "r")
yaml_file = yaml.load_all(stream)
for doc in yaml_file:
print(doc['displayName'])
print(doc['additionalAttributes']['externalIPs']
```

5.Return back to console ,Run the command to list all the external IP addresses.

```
       python filename.py
```

For more information refer to the link:

https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-resources#gcloud

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in python with the following code:

```
from google.cloud.asset import AssetServiceClient
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict


def get_ip(credentials, projects):
    client = AssetServiceClient(credentials=credentials)
    for project in projects:
        params = {
                "scope": f"projects/{project['number']}",
                "asset_types": ["compute.googleapis.com/Address"]
            }
        while True:
            request = client.search_all_resources(
                **params
            )
            for page in request.pages:
                data = MessageToDict(page._pb)
                for asset in data.get('results', []):
                    yield asset
            if request.next_page_token:
                params['page_token'] = request.next_page_token
            else:
                break
```

First, you have to install the following library `google-cloud-asset` with `pip`. (`pip install google-cloud-asset`).

The function will create a generator with the asset objects. With the appropriate credentials and a list of projects you can list all the IP address from you `GCP` environment.