# optimize my bash script with gcloud commands

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, scripting, gcloud

Could you help me with optimizing this script for me? This is grabbing all the meta data from our total organization and currently this script takes any where between 12-13 hours to complete. But I want to run this multiple times a weeks, is there a way to optimize it and get the results faster?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PROJECTS=$(gcloud projects list --format='get(projectId)')
FILE="instances.csv"
rm $FILE
touch $FILE
START_TIME=$SECONDS
COUNTER=1
TOTAL=0
echo 'name,organization,space,zone,machine_type,preemptible,internal_ip,external_ip,status,service_account,project_id' >> $FILE
for project_id in $PROJECTS
do
  ((TOTAL=TOTAL+1))
done
for project_id in $PROJECTS
do
  echo 'project ' $COUNTER 'of' $TOTAL
  echo $project_id
  ORG=$(gcloud projects describe $project_id --format="get(labels.organization)")
  echo $ORG
  SPACE=$(gcloud projects describe $project_id --format="get(labels.space)")
  echo $SPACE
  gcloud compute instances list --project $project_id --format="csv(
   name,
   format("$ORG",''),
   format("$SPACE", ''),
   zone.basename(),
   machineType.machine_type().basename(),
   scheduling.preemptible.yesno(yes=true, no=''),
   networkInterfaces[].networkIP.notnull().list():label=INTERNAL_IP,
   networkInterfaces[].accessConfigs[0].natIP.notnull().list():label=EXTERNAL_IP,
   status,
   serviceAccounts[0].email
  )" | awk 'NR>1' | sed s/$/,$project_id/ >> $FILE
  ((COUNTER=COUNTER+1))
  ELAPSED_TIME=$(($SECONDS - $START_TIME))
  echo 'Elapsed time -' "$(($ELAPSED_TIME/60)) min $(($ELAPSED_TIME%60)) sec"
done
ELAPSED_TIME=$(($SECONDS - $START_TIME))
  echo 'Elapsed time -' "$(($ELAPSED_TIME/60)) min $(($ELAPSED_TIME%60)) sec"
```

Comment: https://wiki.c2.com/?RulesOfOptimizationClub -> Rule 2. and 3. . What takes the most time in the script? What affects the execution time the most? First, check your script with http://shellcheck.net

Comment: I know over all script takes time because it has to print meta data from 1600 gcp projects. But my script hungs for a while sometimes. First time it took 10hrs to complete after each re run its taking more time which is unreliable for me in this scenario.

Comment: A tool that needs to process 1600 projects should not be a shell script. Just staring the CLI can takes multiple seconds. For thousands of commands that would save hours of runtime. 1) Rewrite your script into a program using a language such as Python or Go. 2) Most commands could then run in parallel.

Comment: John - I knew the python and GO are better in processing massive data but I don't know either of them that is why I chose bash. Do you have expertise on it? can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the challenge interesting, especially with concurrency in Go, and I made it.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "google.golang.org/api/cloudresourcemanager/v1"
    "google.golang.org/api/compute/v1"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

var listSeparator = ";"

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", ListProject)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func ListProject(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    svc, err := cloudresourcemanager.NewService(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    svcCompute, err := compute.NewService(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    prjlist, err := svc.Projects.List().Do()
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    waitGroup := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    c := make(chan line)
    finished := make(chan string)

    waitGroup.Add(len(prjlist.Projects))

    for _, prj := range prjlist.Projects {
        go listInstances(*prj, svcCompute, c, waitGroup)
    }
    go func() {
        waitGroup.Wait()
        finished <- ""
    }()

    fmt.Fprint(w, "name,organization,space,zone,machine_type,preemptible,internal_ip,external_ip,status,service_account,project_id\n")

    loop:
        for {
            select {
            case l := <-c:
                fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%t,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", l.projectName,l.organization,l.space,l.zone,l.machineType,l.preemtible,l.internalIps,l.externalIps,l.status,l.serviceAccount,l.projectId)
            case <- finished:
                break loop
            }
        }
}

func listInstances(prj cloudresourcemanager.Project, svcCompute *compute.Service, c chan line, group *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer group.Done()

    zoneList, err := svcCompute.Zones.List(prj.ProjectId).Do()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    group.Add(len(zoneList.Items))

    for _, zone := range zoneList.Items {
        go listInstanceInZone(*zone, prj, svcCompute, c, group)
    }
}

func listInstanceInZone(zone compute.Zone, prj cloudresourcemanager.Project, svcCompute *compute.Service, c chan line, group *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer group.Done()
    instList, err := svcCompute.Instances.List(prj.ProjectId, zone.Name).Do()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    for _, inst := range instList.Items {

        internalIps := ""
        externalIps := ""

        for _, n := range inst.NetworkInterfaces {
            for _, a := range n.AccessConfigs {
                if externalIps != "" {
                    externalIps += listSeparator
                }
                externalIps += a.NatIP
            }
            if internalIps != "" {
                internalIps += listSeparator
            }
            internalIps += n.NetworkIP
        }

        sacEmails := ""
        for _, s := range inst.ServiceAccounts {
            if sacEmails != "" {
                sacEmails += listSeparator
            }
            sacEmails += s.Email
        }

        machineTypeLastIndex := strings.LastIndex(inst.MachineType,"/")
        l := line{
            projectName:    prj.Name,
            projectId:      prj.ProjectId,
            organization:   prj.Labels["labels.organization"],
            space:          prj.Labels["labels.space"],
            zone:           zone.Name,
            machineType:    inst.MachineType[machineTypeLastIndex+1:],
            preemtible:     inst.Scheduling.Preemptible,
            internalIps:    internalIps,
            externalIps:    externalIps,
            status:         inst.Status,
            serviceAccount: sacEmails,
        }
        c <- l
    }

}

type line struct {
    projectName    string
    projectId      string
    organization   string
    space          string
    zone           string
    machineType    string
    preemtible     bool
    internalIps    string
    externalIps    string
    status         string
    serviceAccount string
}
```

There might have more elegant, or some issue in the expected results, but it works in few seconds instead of few minutes (without concurrency)